# What version of Scala does Apache Flink use?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm getting started with Apache Flink. I noticed on the Apache Flink download page, it says "Apache Flink 1.14.3 for Scala 2.11 (asc, sha512)" as the name of the installation file.

Can you confirm there is no Apache Flink for Scala 3.x? I want to make sure I download the right version of Scala

Comment: You don't need to download nor install **Scala**, **Flink** should embed its own **Scala**.

Comment: When I `cd` into the `flink-1.14.3` folder and run /bin/start-local.sh, I get this output: `zsh: no such file or directory: ./bin/start-local.sh`

Comment: That is the sources, you want to download the binaries: https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Great, that is the correct answer. If you post it below, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink up to 1.14 is available in both a Scala 2.11 and Scala 2.12 binary, which can be downloaded from https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html. This means that you can use Flink's Scala API with either Scala 2.11 or Scala 2.12.

In Flink 1.15 (the next version), support for Scala 2.11 is dropped. Next to that, all Java APIs are independent from Scala. You can find more information at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23986

This means that if you would like to use Scala 3.0 in combination with Flink 1.15, that's possible. You can find some examples at https://github.com/sjwiesman/flink-scala-3

Comment: > In Flink 1.15 (the next version), support for Scala 2.11 is dropped. 

Does this mean Flink will no longer ship with Scala inside the binary file?

Comment: Flink 1.15 will still be bundled with Scala, but you can opt-in to a Scala-free Flink. See the release notes at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23986 for all details

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the community so this is really helpful for me